# The requested URL /image.jpeg was not found on this server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

I've got a Laravel in hosting company and I get this error:

```
The requested URL /image.jpeg was not found on this server.
```

This also happens with some `CSS` and `JS` files but not all the files. What could be? In my `localhost` environment everything works fine. Can it be some CPanel configuration that I'm missing?

Thank you :)

Comment: To start with the basics, have you checked that the file `public/image.jpeg` in your repository exists and is readable?

Comment: please share your folder structure and yes @ceejayoz is right check whether it exists in your repo and is readable?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is use `asset()` function. For example, I have `example1.js` file that I want to import/include/use in my application, I have to use the following code.

`<script src="{{ asset('example1.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>`

If you want to load image named `exampleimage.jpg`, You have to use the following code.

`<img src="{{ asset('exampleimage.jpg') }}" />`

You have to store images, Javascript, and CSS in `public` folder.

Let me know if it works. According to your question, this is your answer. Let me know if you have any more questions.